# How to update/check the ubuntu kernel configuration?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I am new to Linux, and currently I want to try `Kubernetes` in my laptop. The official tutorial says

1. You need to have docker installed on one machine.
2. Your kernel should support memory and swap accounting. Ensure that the following configs are turned on in your linux kernel:
   CONFIG_RESOURCE_COUNTERS=y
   CONFIG_MEMCG=y
   CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP=y
   CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED=y
   CONFIG_MEMCG_KMEM=y

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I dont know whether the above configs are already turned on or not, how to check them? and if some are still off, how to turn them on?

Comment: The config can be seen in the file `/boot/config-\`uname -r\``. As for how to turn them on, that is too broad a question for Stackoverflow as it requires recompilation and reinstallation of a Linux kernel. But there are plenty of tutorials out there on that exact topic so do a search.

Comment: I think the next step in the guide tells you how to turn them on: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md#prerequisites. Also just fyi, if you just want to take kubernetes for a spin on your local host, you can try local-up-cluster.sh (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/locally.md#starting-the-cluster).